# Error :Binary XML file line : Inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I have an activity `MainActivity` in which I have and fragment `signup_fragment` I want to call fragment from an activity but it gives an exception of `Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment`

and `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.pickingredients.MainActivity@d9ff1e7 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Below are my code

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val fragment=Signup()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.sigup_fragment,fragment).commit()

    }
```

**SignupFragment**

```
class Signup : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false)
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
        listener?.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    } }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@color/light_grey">

    <TextView
            android:text="@string/what_is_your_mood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/mood_tv"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.03"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:id="@+id/guideline" app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp"
                                                android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <fragment
            android:layout_width="362dp"
            android:layout_height="98dp" android:name="com.example.pickingredients.ImagesliderFragment"
            android:id="@+id/sigup_fragment" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mood_tv"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_signup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".Signup">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where is your XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here **`com.example.pickingredients.ImagesliderFragment`**. Either this fragment not found or having issues on that fragment.

And you should use `FrameLayout` instead of `Fragment` in xml.

Moreover your **`MainActivity`** should implement **`OnFragmentInteractionListener`**

Comment: After edit this line problem is still there 
  `android:name="com.example.pickingredients.Signup"`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `android:name` tag from <fragment .../>..

And use `FrameLayout` instead of fragment.

Or you can use below code.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:id="@+id/sigup_fragment"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mood_tv" />
```

Comment: It also gives an exception on SIgnup.kt that 

`must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener`

Comment: I have seen you code.. OnFragmentInteractionListener is not needed as I understand, so you can remove all things related to that listener.